# Create Graphviz labels with subscripts from Java application

Tags: java, graphviz, dot

I am calling Graphviz from Java application using the [Graphviz.java](https://github.com/jabbalaci/graphviz-java-api) API and save the output graph to PDF file.  I need to label some nodes with math subscripts and accents (for example `$a_1$` or `$\hat{a}$` in latex). I can survive with subscripts only.

is there anyway to do it? is this because of the API i'm using or I am missing something here.

I have tried `b [label=<x<SUB>1</SUB>>];` but it doesn't work (though symbols like `a [ label=<&#945;>];` work and show up in the output file).

Comment: According to their documentation[http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html], >>NOTE:The font markups for bold, italic, underlining, subscript and superscript (<B>, <I>, <U>, <SUB>; and <SUP>) are only available in versions after 14 October 2011, and are currently only available via the cairo and svg renderers. In addition, the horizontal and vertical rules (<HR> and <VR>) are only available in versions later than 8 July 2011.
Are you sure you are using either of those versions?

Comment: @npinti I just tried rendering subscripts to .SVG and it works. seems accents out of scope. please convert your comment to an answer Thanks!

Comment: Done. I have been going at the same problem myself for some time and this is the only logical conlcusion. I have moved my comment as per your recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to their [documentation](http://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html),

> NOTE:The font markups for bold, italic, underlining, subscript and
>   superscript (`<B>`, `<I>`, `<U>`, `<SUB>;` and `<SUP>`) are only available in
>   versions after 14 October 2011, and are currently only available via
>   the cairo and svg renderers. In addition, the horizontal and vertical
>   rules (`<HR>` and `<VR>`) are only available in versions later than 8 July
>   2011.

Are you sure you are using either of those versions?

Comment: don't know how to know the version under my mac system but rendering to svg allowed me to have subscripts (unlike pdf or gif )

Comment: I have version 2.34.0, from 2014.  Like the OP, the problem is that SUB and SUP are supported, but are ostensibly broken when outputting to PNG.