# DOT/graphviz node labels not displaying HTML-like subscripts

Tags: graphviz, dot

Graphviz's [HTML-like labels documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) suggests I can have a node labeled Uₓ with this `.dot` file:

```
digraph G {
    U [label=<U<SUB>X</SUB>>];
    U->X
}
```

Unfortunately, the graph produced shows a node with UX instead of Uₓ:

[image]

Am I missing something to make the X in Uₓ subscript?

***UPDATE***: I'm outputting PNG images with `dot mygraph.dot -Tpng -o mygraph.png` and receive *no warnings or errors*. The version is:

```
$ dot -V
dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)
```

Installed with `brew` on macOS

***UPDATE 2***: I tried to output SVG with `-Tsvg` instead of PNG with `-Tpng` and I do get a subscript `X`, sort of. The font size of `X` is exactly the same as `U`, just shifted down a little. Why is this so bad?

[image]

Comment: I got an image that shows a subscript (a bit large though) when using the dot executable directly like `dot -Tpng ...`. When using a web service (http://www.webgraphviz.com/) I got "Warning: Not built with libexpat. Table formatting is not available. in label of node U". Did you get a warning / error ?

Comment: Should work when generating svg - are you?

Comment: Was going to link the documentation for the limitations as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669014/create-graphviz-labels-with-subscripts-from-java-application), but it seems like subscripts don't work with all output formats and versions of graphviz.

Comment: I use the command `dot mygraph.dot -Tpng > mygraph.png` to generate PNG images. I received zero warnings or errors.

Comment: I'm using dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304).

Comment: I'm using the same version on Cygwin and here I don't have the problems.

Comment: @albert, are you using the same `.dot` file I posted above? I'm using macOS, maybe graphviz's macOS version has problems with subscripts...

Comment: Yes I did use the example you provided and I also see that the X is not smaller (though it is shifted down a little bit more than in your case).

Answer (score 0):

I was not satisfied with my comment so I'll try to give a bit a better overview with what I see (so no answer, but just a summary).
For this overview I used the following input:

```
digraph G {
    U [label=<U<sub>x</sub>>];
    U->X
    V [label=<U<SUB>x</SUB>>];
    V->X
    V1 [label=<Ux>];
    V1->X
    W [label=<U<sub>X</sub>>];
    W->X
    Y [label=<U<SUB>X</SUB>>];
    Y->X
    Y1 [label=<UX>];
    Y1->X
}
```

and the following versions of dot:

- Windows: dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
- Cygwin: dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)

The results are as follows:

**Windows png**:

[image]

**Windows svg**:

[image]

**Cygwin png**:

[image]

**Cygwin svg**:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, for you, SVG disregards the `<sub>` markup and PNG does output subscripts, but poorly. For me, on macOS, it's the opposite. My SVG output looks similar to your PNG and vice-versa.